# Is there anyway to delete a specified character in a string?

Tags: java, string

This is my code

```
public class StringTest {
    
    public static void main(String []args) {
            String str= "8650";
            StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(str);
            char index = str.charAt(0);
            System.out.println(index+"");
            int indexStr= build.indexOf(index+"");
            System.out.println(indexStr);

            for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(indexStr == 0)    
            build.deleteCharAt(indexStr);
            }
           System.out.println(build);
    }
}
```

I want to delete thé first number if it’s 0

So if I have 8650 it will print 8650, instead if I have 0650 it will print 650.

Answer (score 1):

You have made things complicated,just use `String.startsWith()` and  String.substring()`` can do it

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "8650";
        str = "0650";
        if (str.startsWith("0")) {
            str = str.substring(1);
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's even easier: `str = str.replaceAll("^0", "");`

Answer (score 1):

> Below code might help you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String val = "10456";
    val = (val.charAt(0) == '0') ? val.substring(1, val.length()) : val;
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will remove all leading zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "000650";
    str = str.replaceFirst("^0*", "");
    System.out.println(str); // output 650 it will remove all leading zero
}
```